# Extract Tab icon with jquery?

Tags: jquery

How i will get the href tag of the shortcut-icon here,please help i have extracted htmldata of entire page.

how i will get this?.

```
$.get(url, function (data) { 
      alert("Page Source: " + data); 
      var htmlData = data.toString();
      alert("HtmlData"+htmlData);
      var icon = htmlData($('link[rel="shortcut icon"]').attr('href'));
      alert("icon"+icon);//Not getting icon url 

    });
```

Html has

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico">
```

Is there is any solution?.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$.get(url, function (data) {
  var icon = $(data).find('link[rel="shortcut icon"]').attr('href');
  alert("icon"+icon); 
});
```

Comment: I have one qustion from ur ans. can we select any element from HTML text ..to?

Comment: yes!!! you can.... but you need to make sure the HTML that was return is jquery obejct to use jquery methods... like i did here with `data` `$(data)`

Comment: hmm thanks.. bofore this I think we can select only dom elements

Comment: I am getting error as undefined I can see a object of data but icon is undefined.wht is wrong?

Comment: what you hvae in `data` ... HTML  ??

Comment: Shows just a object,when i put like this   var htmlData = data.toString();It gives the entire source of selected tab.

Comment: if it give the source then above answer should work .. no need to convert it to string... just add the aboce code... and yes check for error in console tab..

Comment: this should work... make sure there is no corss domin issues... you are not getting the html from other domains

Comment: I am unsure why console are not printing but getting alerts,$(data) --- Alert is [object Object],icon---- Alert is undefined

Comment: can you show me your server side code... what are you sending  the response as??

Comment: chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
 console.log('Inside Tab');
   var url = tab.url;
   alert("Url"+url);
    $.get(url, function (data) { 
      
     alert(data);
     var icon = $(data).find('link[rel="shortcut icon"]').attr('href');
     alert("icon"+icon);
      
    }); 


});

Comment: Is there any other solution to add id to icon or regex expression could some one help me

Comment: what do you mean add id ??

Comment: bipen,the method you have done not works for me,Is it possible to add some random id to this <link rel="shortcut icon" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico"> so i can extract using $("#randomId").attr('href')